# How to write Multiple chaincodes for multiple channels in hyperledger-composer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

In Fabric we have multiple channels, if my network has multiple channels then how can i write multiple chaincodes for each channel from the Hyperledger-composer ?

Comment: With fabric you instantiate chaincode on a specific channel. It's similar in composer you would deploy or start a business network on a specific channel. You can deploy the same or different business networks on different channels

Answer (score 1):

Hyperledger Composer connects to Fabric via Business Network Cards, and the Cards include a connection profile.  In that connection profile the channel is specified.  By default **composerchannel** is used.

You can see this in a filename similar to this example: `/home/ibm/.composer/cards/admin@my-network/connection.json`